# Spring Data @EntityGraph performs LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of INNER JOIN

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Having following parent-child entity definitions, when using Spring's `@EntityGraph` performs a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`.

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "gid", updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "...")
  private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "type_id", nullable = false, columDefinition='...')
  private Type type;

  // ...
```

```
@Entity
public class Type {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "gid", updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "...")
  private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();

  // ...
```

```
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, UUID> {

  @EntityGraph(attributePaths = "type")
  Optional<Parent> findOneWithTypeById(UUID id);
```

The `ParentRepository#findOneWithTypeById` results in a `LEFT JOIN` although I specied `type` is `optional=false` and `nullable=false`.

There should be enough information for Spring/JPA to generate a query with an INNER JOIN here ?

Comment: Why inner join needed ?

Comment: `There should be enough information for Spring/JPA to generate a query with an INNER JOIN` <- Neither Spring nor JPA generate queries, the underlying JPA implementation does. Is that hibernate in you case? Or what else? And what is the problem with it not using an inner join. Do you have an error / unexpected behavior because of it?

Comment: I know it's Hibernate (in this case) that generates the query, but that is not my point. 
I also know that using INNER join wont change the results... I'm just wondering how hibernate chooses a LEFT join here ? I guess performance wise it doesn't really matter for this query, but still... It would be more clear if the query was using an INNER as LEFT implies the type is nullable...